# Как узнать ip сайта через JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, firefox-extension

Как через API расширений браузера firefox узнать IP сайта. Ну или преобразовать URL в IP.
Во всех методах вроде передается только URL.

Comment: Зачем? А если на одном IP крутятся десяток сайтов? А если сайт хостится на разных IP?

Comment: Это нужно чтоб определять сеть одного оверлея